# Saving a user's favorites

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to associate a user authenticated with passport.js with a backbone.js collection or an array of ids (I don't which solution is the best) and save this in mongoDB.
I use node.js on server side.

Is it possible?

(for instance saving a user's favorites).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a User schema like this:

```
var User = new Schema({
    favorites: [{
        whatHaveYou: String,
    }]
})
```

Now, with using passport.js, after you have authenticating the user with this schema, you will be able to access the favorites with: `req.user.favorites`.

I suggest you go throw this demo project on github for setting up a node-express-mongoose project with passportjs if you have any more questions: https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo, this helped me a lot.

Comment: @yowza did this help any?